# ArcGIS Online if-else in symbology expression

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, expression

I'm trying to use ArcGIS online symbology expression with the if else statement.
Code I’m using is:

```js
    var dif1=$feature.Object
    var dif2=$feature.Unit
    var dif3=$feature.Object_1
    var dif4=$feature.Unit_1
    var var1
    if ( dif1 == dif2 and dif3 == dif4){
        var1 = "test";
    }
    return var1
```

Is there a way to use 2 statements in 1 if line like I’m trying?

Error I get is “Parse Error:Line 9: Unexpected identifier”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [help file about operators](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/logic/#operators) in the Arcade language.

I believe your code needs to be this:

```js
var dif1=$feature.Object;
var dif2=$feature.Unit;
var dif3=$feature.Object_1;
var dif4=$feature.Unit_1;
var var1;
if ( dif1 == dif2 && dif3 == dif4){
    var1 = "test";
}
return var1;
```